# Select Box and Input Box on Same Line in table row

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get a select dropdown to stay in the same line as an input box in a table row but the input box keeps going to the next line. I tried to wrap them both in a div with `display:inline-block` but it doesn't work.

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="display:inline-block">
          <select id="ajaxtypes">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="type" style="width:100%; background-color:#fff000">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="type" style="width:100%; background-color:#fff000">
      </td> 
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="type" style="width:100%; background-color:#fff000">
      </td> 
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="type" style="width:100%; background-color:#fff000">
      </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/4s5v749h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<div style="white-space: nowrap">`. Or you can even put that style on the `<td>`.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have put width:100% to your input text. Try reducing it and it will work

Comment: Can you please explain how reducing width will work?

Comment: Just make it something less than 64% and run it

Answer (score 0):

The `display: inline-block` setting has to be applied to the elements themselves, not their parent element:

```
<div >
   <select id="ajaxtypes" style="display:inline-block">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" name="type" style="width:100%; background-color:#fff000; display:inline-block;">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Remove style `width:100%;` from the input next to select.

Code snippet below

```
<td>
          <select id="ajaxtypes">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="type" style=" background-color:#fff000">
      </td>
```